# python: how to stop For loop at certain list index when push button is pressed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a simple game. I have 5 leds connected to each GPIO pin and one push button to another GPIO pin. When the game start, the led will go on/off subsequently that gives perception of running. When the button is pushed I want that only one led is on. The script that I wrote below did that, but the problem is, it is only the led connected to the first GPIO listed in the list (index 0) that on.
I want to know if there is way to break the FOR LOOPS at any list index. With the script below, the break only happens when FOR LOOPS has looped through the index in the list.
Here is my script:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

Switch=21
GPIO.setup(Switch, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

LedList=[5,6,26,13,19]
for i in LedList:
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)

#test
GPIO.output(LedList, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(0.5)
GPIO.output(LedList, GPIO.LOW)

def runlight():
    for i in LedList:
        print "L.e.d ",i
        GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        if input_state==True:
            GPIO.output(i, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.1)

        elif input_state==False:
            print "button pressed at ",i
            GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)
            break
try:
    while True:
        input_state=GPIO.input(Switch)
        runlight()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
GPIO.cleanup()
```

I am new in python, thanks for your help.

Comment: you just need to move your `input_state=GPIO.input(Switch)` line to inside the for loop in `runlight` i'd suggest you put it either just before the if statement

Comment: You can exit a loop with `break` command.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt reply. I tried what @JamesKent suggested. the input_state=GPIO.input(Switch) now just before if statement inside the for loop. It works!, the condition under elif is executed, means the led stays on. 
One problem, the break does not really break. The index 0 (pin 5) is still executed, as result there are two leds that turn on, led when button is pushed and led of pin 5. Here is the result of the loop print: 
5,
6,
26,
13,
19,
button pressed at  19 <--pressed,
5,
button pressed at  5 <--hold button,
5 <--button released,
6,
26,
...
any suggestion?

Comment: I finally found the problem. I just need to put 'time.sleep(1)' after 'GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)'. After sleep, then 'GPIO.output(i, GPIO.LOW)'. I remove the 'break'. it works now as expected. thanks for the inspiration. problem solved.